# Reactjs map function causing the whole page to go blank

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

im putting both my back and front end together and after i fetched my data with Effect Hook i mapped the data and retuned the article title in an h2 tag ,and the map function causes the whole page to go blank ,but when i comment out that part the page seems to work just fine.

```
import './App.css';
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";



function App() {

const [articles,setArticles] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/articles',{
        'method':'GET',
        headers: {
            'content-Type':'application/json',
            'Authorization':'Token a9714c85387c802207740a7bd8882f4a748733be',
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => setArticles())
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
},[])

  return (
    <div className="App">

        <h3> Django & Reactjs Blog App</h3>

        {articles.map(article =>{
            return <h2> {article.title} </h2>

        })}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I expected the page to load just as normal but with an article with dummy title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the response you got and save it to your state using set function.

```
.then(response => setArticles(response.data.articles))
```